# Android Studio, lists and sqli-database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am a new user of android studio and I have a question about list. I will extract from the database, list all activities (class activities) stored in the database (mapActivity, attractionsActivity, etc. Such activities when creating a new empty activity class). This should be listed in Main Activity. I hope you understand what I mean. i'm using sqlite database

//DBhelper

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_name = "Mydb";
    private static final int DB_version = 1;

    private String createActivityTypeQuery = "CREATE TABLE activity_type (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, type TEXT)";
    private String createpriceQuery = "CREATE TABLE price (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, price TEXT)";

    private String createActivityQuery = "CREATE TABLE activity (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                                            + "name TEXT,"
                                            + "description TEXT,"
                                            + "type INTEGER,"
                                            + "homePage TEXT,"
                                            + "price INTEGER,"
                                            + "outdoor NUMERIC,"
                                            + "FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES activity_type(_id),"
                                            + "FOREIGN KEY (price) REFERENCES price(_id)"
                                            + ")";

    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DB_name, null, DB_version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(createActivityTypeQuery);
        db.execSQL(createpriceQuery);
        db.execSQL(createActivitytQuery);

        insertActivityType(db, "Amusement park");
        insertActivityType(db, "Waterpark");
        insertprice(db, "Low");
        insertprice(db, "Medium");
        insertprice(db, "High");
        insertActivity(db, "Thorpe park", "Amusement park in London, United Kingdom. Carousels and roller coaster plus much more", 1, "www.thorpark.uk", 3, true);
        insertActivity(db, "Lee Water Centre", "Lee Water Centre in London, United Kindgom. Lots of water and fun", 2, "www.LeeWaterCentre.uk", 2, true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    private static void insertActivityType(SQLiteDatabase db, String type) {
        ContentValues activityValues = new ContentValues();
        aktivitetValues.put("type", type);
        db.insert("activity_type", null, activityValues);
    }

    private static void insertprice(SQLiteDatabase db, String price) {
        ContentValues priceValues = new ContentValues();
        priceValues.put("price", price);
        db.insert("price", null, priceValues);
    }

    private static void insertActivity(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String 
    description, int type, String webPage, int price, boolean outdoor) {
        ContentValues activityValues = new ContentValues();
        activitytValues.put("name", name);
        activitytValues.put("description", description);
        activitytValues.put("type", type);
        activityValues.put("webPage", webPage);
        activitytValues.put("price", price);
        activityValues.put("outdoor", outdoor);
        db.insert("activity", null, activityValues);
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView activitylist = findViewById(R.id.activitylist);

        //Database
        SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);


        try {
            db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            cursor = db.query("activity", new String[] {"_id", "name", "description"}, null, null, null, null, null);
            SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, new String[]{"name", "description"}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },0);
            activitylist.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        } catch(SQLiteException e) {
            Toast dbToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Database Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            dbToast.show();
        }
    } // end onCreate()

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you issue could be due to there being no data in the **activity** table due to there not being (according to the activity table's create SQL) a column named **webPage**, instead you probably want to insert the data into the **homePage** column.

This a good example of why it is recommended to define table and column names with a static variable and then ALWAYS use that variable to refer to the table/column.

The short fix to your solution could be to use :-

```
private static void insertActivity(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String 
description, int type, String webPage, int price, boolean outdoor) {
    ContentValues activityValues = new ContentValues();
    activitytValues.put("name", name);
    activitytValues.put("description", description);
    activitytValues.put("type", type);
    activityValues.put("homePage", webPage); //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
    activitytValues.put("price", price);
    activityValues.put("outdoor", outdoor);
    db.insert("activity", null, activityValues);
}
```

However a better solution would be to do something along the lines of :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_name = "Mydb";
    private static final int DB_version = 1;

    private static TB_ACTIVITY = "activity"; // DEFINED constant variable for the TABLE NAME
    private static ACTIVITY_COL_HOMEPAGE = "homePage"; //<<<<<<<<<< DEFINES constant variable for the COLUMN NAME
    .......... other columns done likewise

    private String createActivityTypeQuery = "CREATE TABLE activity_type (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, type TEXT)";
    private String createpriceQuery = "CREATE TABLE price (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, price TEXT)";

    private String createActivityQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + TB_ACTIVITY + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " //<<<<<<<<<< APPLIED constant variable for the TABLE NAME
                                            + "name TEXT,"
                                            + "description TEXT,"
                                            + "type INTEGER,"
                                            + ACTIVITY_COL_HOMEPAGE + " TEXT," //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED TO USE constant
                                            + "price INTEGER,"
                                            + "outdoor NUMERIC,"
                                            + "FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES activity_type(_id),"
                                            + "FOREIGN KEY (price) REFERENCES price(_id)"
                                            + ")";

    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DB_name, null, DB_version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(createActivityTypeQuery);
        db.execSQL(createpriceQuery);
        db.execSQL(createActivitytQuery);

        insertActivityType(db, "Amusement park");
        insertActivityType(db, "Waterpark");
        insertprice(db, "Low");
        insertprice(db, "Medium");
        insertprice(db, "High");
        insertActivity(db, "Thorpe park", "Amusement park in London, United Kingdom. Carousels and roller coaster plus much more", 1, "www.thorpark.uk", 3, true);
        insertActivity(db, "Lee Water Centre", "Lee Water Centre in London, United Kindgom. Lots of water and fun", 2, "www.LeeWaterCentre.uk", 2, true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    private static void insertActivityType(SQLiteDatabase db, String type) {
        ContentValues activityValues = new ContentValues();
        aktivitetValues.put("type", type);
        db.insert("activity_type", null, activityValues);
    }

    private static void insertprice(SQLiteDatabase db, String price) {
        ContentValues priceValues = new ContentValues();
        priceValues.put("price", price);
        db.insert("price", null, priceValues);
    }

    private static void insertActivity(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String 
    description, int type, String webPage, int price, boolean outdoor) {
        ContentValues activityValues = new ContentValues();
        activitytValues.put("name", name);
        activitytValues.put("description", description);
        activitytValues.put("type", type);
        activityValues.put(ACTIVITY_COL_HOMEPAGE, webPage); //<<<<<<<<<<
        activitytValues.put("price", price);
        activityValues.put("outdoor", outdoor);
        db.insert(TB_ACTIVITY, null, activityValues); //<<<<<<<<<<
    }
}
```

- **Note the above code is in-principle code, it has not been tested and may therefore have some minor errors.**
- The error was the first error found there is no guarantee that other errors do not exist.
- See all lines that have been marked with `//<<<<<<<<<<`
- A constant has only been applied for the ***homePage*** column, ideally you should do the same for all columns, if adopting this better approach. Ideally you'd make the constants **public** they could then be used elsewhere e.g.

  - `cursor = db.query("activity", new String[] {"_id", "name", "description"}, null, null, null, null, null);`
  - could become (assuming naming convention above were utilised for the constants)
    `cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TB_ACTIVITY, new String[] {DBHelper.ACTIVITY_ID,DBHelper.NAME,DBHelper.DESCRIPTION}, null, null, null, null, null);`